# Customised virtual function

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have to design a library using C++ and following are my requirements.

1. Users should be able to extend my API class methods
2. User implemented virtual methods will be called inside of the library polymorphically
3. I have to put two log entries before and after each virtual method call
4. When user creates his/her own classes and virtual methods, AND if he/she uses my library (has a link to), in addition to normal dynamic binding, above point 3 (having two log entries) should be satisfied

The idea could be sketched out like this?

```
class BaseClass
{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};
```

User implementation would be like

```
class DerivedClass: public BaseClass
{
public:
    virtual void foo() {/*come impl*/}
};
```

Using following code,

```
BaseClass * bp = new DerivedClass();
bp->foo();
```

Should be equivalent to something like,

```
BaseClass * bp = new DerivedClass();
log_start(typeid(*bp).name());
bp->foo();
log_end(typeid(*bp).name());
```

But I can't ask my library users (and even I cann't do in everywhere) to put these logging stuff whenever they use my API. Since, there are a lot of virtual functions and their usage, I can't put logging everywhere in my lib.

Is there any easy way to achieve this? Do I need to create my own virtual table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use something like the ***[Template Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)*** pattern for this case

```
class BaseClass
{
public:
    void foo() {
         log_start(typeid(*this).name()); 
         doFoo(); 
         log_end(typeid(*this).name()); 
    }
protected:
    virtual void doFoo() = 0;
};
```

---

```
class DerivedClass: public BaseClass
{
protected: // or private, depends on use case
    virtual void doFoo() {/* some impl */}
};
```

---

```
int main() {
    BaseClass * bp = new DerivedClass();
    bp->foo();
    delete bp;
    return 0;
}
```

See a working sample [here](http://ideone.com/AotMnP).

Comment: Thanks, nice technique

Answer (score 3):

Instead of making them call `foo` directly, you could have the user implement `foo`, but call `bar` instead. `bar` would wrap the call to `foo`, like in:

```
class BaseClass { 
public:
    void bar() {
        log_start(typeid(*this).name());
        foo();
        log_end(typeid(*this).name());
    }

protected:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};
```

Usage would be:

```
BaseClass * bp = new DerivedClass();
bp->bar();
```